# How can I pull data from website using C#

Tags: c#, .net

Web-page data into the application

Comment: Access to their API would be ideal. Otherwise 'scraping' the page might or might not be an option.

Comment: Looking at the XHR requests in my browser inspector I notice a `/america/scan` request. The response contains 80 numbers among which the values for the oscillators/averages list, but not the data behind the buy/sell dials. Would the number list suffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replicate the request the website makes to get a list of relevant numbers. The following code might be a good start.

```
var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("<url>");
httpRequest.Method = "POST";
httpRequest.Accept = "application/json";
string postData = "{<json payload>}";
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpRequest.GetRequestStream())) {
    streamWriter.Write(postData);
}

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) httpRequest.GetResponse();
string result;
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())) {
    result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Now, for the `<url>` and `<json payload>` values:

1. Open the web inspector in your browser.
2. Go to the Network tab.
3. Set it so Fetch/XHR/AJAX requests are shown.
4. Refresh the page.
5. Look for a request that you want to replicate.
6. Copy the request URL.
7. Copy the Payload (JSON data, to use it in your code you'll have to add a `\` before every `"`)

Side note: The owner of the website you are making automated requests to might not be very happy about your tool, and you/it might be blocked if it makes too many requests in a short time.